# Having android application respond to soft keyboard input without displaying the input

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm relatively new to Android and have just spent several days discovering approaches that don't work for what I'm trying to do. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

My current need is to display varying text on the screen in response to the user's typed characters on a soft keyboard, without displaying what the user typed. EditText doesn't seem to have been intended for this, but maybe there is something funky I can do like have a hidden EditText field to snag the letters using onTextChanged, then display the text in the visible TextView field.

I've tried key listeners with a TextView with no luck. (Eclipse frowned strongly, but I thought it was worth a try.)

Any pointers -- including previous stackoverflow questions that I missed -- gratefully accepted.

EDIT: No luck on answers, but I found something that does work. In the XML file, I used an EditText view, but added the following attributes

```
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:editable="false"
```

Don't know enough to know whether this is a nice solution, but it does work.